# when i click on the p:selectBooleanCheckbox, it works but for the second click it doesn't work,why?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jsf-2, selectbooleancheckbox

I have a "`p:selectBooleanCheckbox`" in my xhtml page.
I have inserted this code `selected="true"` to make it checked by default.
SO when i run the page, and click for the first time it becames "unchecked" ,
but since then when i click on it it still unchecked , it doesn't change.
So to reseume =>my p:selectBooleanCheckbox is clickable just once after that when i click on it, it doesn't change (it still unchekeced)

this is the code in my xhtml page:

```
<div class="row">
 <p:outputLabel for="spec_telOwner" value="Propriétaire du num"    styleClass="col-md-3 control-label" />
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-icon right">
       <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  selected="true"  id="spec_telOwner"   value="#{searchEngine.spec.phoneLineOwner}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

i'm using eclipse sts , and i run my application on InternetExplorer.

Comment: first of all edit your question to make it more confortable to read, after that give more detail about your problem like the output that you have after double click

Answer (score -1):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:evoice="http://ccs.tn/taglib/evoice">
    <ui:include src="CloseTicketDialog.xhtml" />

    <div class="form-body pal">
        <div class="row">
            <p:outputLabel for="call_from_tel_number"
                styleClass="col-md-2 control-label" value="Numéro Entrant" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone" />
                    <p:inputText id="call_from_tel_number" maxlength="32" size="9"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.callFromTelNumber}"
                        validatorMessage="Numéro Entrant : Composé au minimum par 8 chiffres dans [0..9]."
                        styleClass="form-control">
                        <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9\s]*" />
                        <f:validateLength minimum="8" maximum="32" />
                        <p:ajax event="blur" id="ajax_call" disabled="#{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                            process="call_from_tel_number,form:growl" 
                            update="form:growl,form:tab_view:lastName, form:tab_view:firstName"
                            listener="#{ticketController.queryOldTickets(ticketController.ticket)}"
                            onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
                            oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p:outputLabel for="reply_to_tel_number" value="Deuxièmme Numéro"
                styleClass="col-md-3 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone" />
                    <p:inputText id="reply_to_tel_number" maxlength="32" size="9"
                        readonly="{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.otherPhonenum}"
                        validatorMessage="Deuxièmme Numéro : Accepte seulement des chiffres dans [0..9]."
                        styleClass="form-control">
                        <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]*" />
                    </p:inputText>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="form-group" />
        <div class="row">
            <p:outputLabel for="telOwner" value="proprietaire de num"
                styleClass="col-md-2 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  selected="true"  id="telOwner" value="#{ticketController.ticket.phoneLineOwner}"  />          

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" />

        <div class="row">
            <p:outputLabel for="lastName" value="#{i18n['name']}"
                styleClass="col-md-2 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <i class="fa fa-user" />
                    <p:inputText id="lastName"
                        readonly="{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.lastName}"
                        styleClass="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <p:outputLabel for="firstName" value="Prénom"
                styleClass="col-md-3 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <i class="fa fa-user" />
                    <p:inputText id="firstName"
                        readonly="{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.firstName}"
                        styleClass="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" />
        <div class="row">
            <p:outputLabel for="subject" value="#{i18n['ticket.purpose']}"
                styleClass="col-md-2 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <p:selectOneMenu style="width:268px" id="subject" filter="true"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" converter="#{ticketSubjectConverter}"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.subject}">
                        <p:ajax event="change" process="subject" update="openTicketRating"
                            listener="#{satisfactionRatingLoV.onSubjectChange(ticketController.ticket.subjectId)}" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Séléctionner Motif" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" itemDisabled="true"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{ticketSubjectLoV.subjects}" var="subject"
                            itemLabel="#{subject.subject}" itemValue="#{subject}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p:outputLabel for="store" value="Magasin"
                styleClass="col-md-3 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <p:selectOneMenu style="width:268px" id="store" filter="true"
                        disabled="{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.store}"
                        converter="#{storeConverter}"
                        >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" itemDisabled="true"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{storeLoV.stores}" var="store" itemLabel="#{store.name}" itemValue="#{store}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" />

        <div class="row">
            <p:outputLabel for="category" styleClass="col-md-2 control-label"
                value="Catégorie" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div>
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="category"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.ticketCategories}"
                        converter="#{ticketCategoryConverter}" label="Séléctionner"
                        style="width:268px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this"
                            update="sub_category_select,view_category"
                            onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
                            oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"
                            listener="#{ticketCategoryLOV.onCategoryChange(ticketController.ticket.ticketCategories)}" />

                        <f:selectItems value="#{ticketCategoryLOV.categories}"
                            var="category" itemValue="#{category}"
                            itemLabel="#{category.name}" />

                        <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                    <p:dataList id="view_category"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.ticketCategories}" var="cat"
                        emptyMessage="">
                                                #{cat.name}
                        </p:dataList>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p:outputLabel for="sub_category_select"
                styleClass="col-md-3 control-label" value="#{i18n['subcategory']}" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div>
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="sub_category_select" style="width:268px"
                        filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" 
                        converter="#{ticketSubCategoryConverter}"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.subCategories}">
                        <p:ajax event="change" process="form:tab_view:sub_category_select"
                            update="view_Subcategories" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Séléctionner Sous Catégorie"
                            noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="#{null}" itemDisabled="true" />
                        <f:selectItems id="selectSubCategoryList"
                            value="#{ticketCategoryLOV.subCategories}" var="subCategory"
                            itemValue="#{subCategory}" itemLabel="#{subCategory.name}" />
                        <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                    <p:dataList id="view_Subcategories"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.subCategories}" var="subCat"
                        emptyMessage="" style="width:300px">
                                                #{subCat.name}
                    </p:dataList>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" />
        <div class="form-group" />
        <div class="row">
            <p:outputLabel for="loyalty_card_owner"
                value="Titulaire Carte. Fid"
                styleClass="col-md-2 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="loyalty_card_owner" style="width:268px"
                        disabled="{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.loyaltyCardOwner}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{i18n['no_response']}" itemValue="NA" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{i18n['yes']}" itemValue="YES" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{i18n['no']}" itemValue="NO" />
                        <p:ajax event="change" process="loyalty_card_owner"
                            update="loyaltycardnumber" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p:outputLabel for="loyaltycardnumber" value="Numéro Carte Fid.:"
                styleClass="col-md-3 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil" />
                    <p:inputText id="loyaltycardnumber"
                        readonly="{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                        disabled="#{ticketController.ticket.loyaltyCardOwner eq 'NA' or ticketController.ticket.loyaltyCardOwner eq 'NO'}"
                        maxlength="15" size="15"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.loyaltyCardNumber}"
                        styleClass="form-control">
                        <f:validateLength minimum="15" maximum="15" />
                    </p:inputText>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" />
        <div class="row">

            <p:outputLabel for="moreInfoPopup" value="Information Fidélité"
                styleClass="col-md-2 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <evoice:loyaltyCard ticket="#{ticketController.ticket}" />
                    <h:graphicImage name="#{jsfProp.img_png_cartefid}"
                        id="moreInfoPopup" onclick="PF('moreInfoDlg').show()"
                        styleClass="img-responsive" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" />
        <div class="row">
            <p:outputLabel for="openTicketRating"
                value="#{i18n['ticket.statisfaction.open']}"
                styleClass="col-md-2 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="openTicketRating" style="width:268px"
                        disabled="#{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                        converter="#{openSatisfactionConverter}"
                        value="#{ticketController.ticket.openSatisfaction}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Satisfaction" itemValue="${null}" />
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{satisfactionRatingLoV.openSatisfactionList}"
                            var="satisfaction" itemLabel="#{satisfaction.lookupValue}"
                            itemValue="#{satisfaction}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p:outputLabel id="label_ticket_a_relancer"
                for="ticket_a_relancer_input" value="Ticket Relance"
                styleClass="col-md-3 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <p:inputText id="ticket_a_relancer_input" styleClass="form-control"
                        readonly="true" value="#{ticketController.ticket.parentTicketId}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" />
        <div class="row">
            <p:outputLabel for="open_tkt_comment"
                value="#{i18n['ticket.comment.open']}"
                styleClass="col-md-2 control-label" />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-icon right">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil" />
                        <p:inputTextarea id="open_tkt_comment" rows="7" cols="120"
                            styleClass="form-control"
                            value="#{ticketController.ticket.openComment}"
                            counter="displayRemainingOpenCmnt" maxlength="4096"
                            counterTemplate="{0} charactère(s) restants." />
                        <h:outputText id="displayRemainingOpenCmnt" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
        closable="true" />
    <div class="form-actions pal">
        <div class="form-group mbn">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <p:commandButton value="Annuler" id="rezetBtn"
                    disabled="{ticketController.ticket.ticketId ne null}"
                    immediate="true" update="form:tab_view" process="@this"
                    actionListener="#{ticketController.reset}">
                    <p:resetInput target="form:tab_view" />
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:spacer width="20" height="20" />
                <p:splitButton value="#{i18n['save']}" type="submit" id="saveButton"
                    onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
                    oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"
                    action="#{ticketController.saveTicket}"
                    actionListener="#{ticketController.validate}"
                    process="form:tab_view:fiche_ticket_tab"
                    update="@form, form:tab_view:tickets_table" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                    >

                    <p:menuitem id="closeTicketCmdBtnWv" value="Clôturer"
                        immediate="true" 
                        disabled="#{ticketController.ticket.ticketId eq null}"
                        icon="ui-icon-locked" onclick="PF('closeTicketDlgWv').show()" >
                        </p:menuitem>
                    <p:menuitem value="Notification" immediate="true"
                        action="/pages/secure/notification/mailbox.xhtml" ajax="false"
                        icon="ui-icon-mail-closed">
                        <f:param id="NotificationParam" name="mail_box_active_tab"
                            value="edit_notification_tab" />
                        <f:param id="NotificationTicketIdParam"
                            name="INIT_NOTIF_TICKET_ID_PARAM"
                            value="#{ticketController.ticket.ticketId}" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                    <p:separator />
                </p:splitButton>
                <p:spacer width="20" height="20" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```